# Prevent commiting in two directiories in the same branch

Tags: git, hash, githooks

I have a git repository containing code in the sources directory and containing the tests in the tests directory.

I would like that a developer can only commit to the sources OR the tests directory within the same branch. So if a developer startet to work in sources he is not allowed anymore to also contribute tests and vice versa.

For another feature that is located in another branch the roles of the persons can change.

I am thinking about git-hooks, especially about a pre-commit-hook on client (I know the developers can work around) and also a pre-push on server (developers do not have access to the hooks directory).

Within the git hook script I would like to get all existing commits (how do I get all hashes of a branch?), check them if there are already changes in the other directory then that which has new changes or if there are new changes in both directories (sources and tests).

Is there a better solution to achieve my needs?

**Update:**
The project is located in a SIL-4 environment (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_integrity_level ), therefore the discussion about the sense of the separation of power of the developers and testers should not be part here. It is simply a requirement and can't be changed.

Comment: my 2c: that seems like a bad requirement -- what have you tried so far?

Comment: why would u want to do this? cmiiw, doesnt this mean smone starting in tests can only commit to tests... and smone starting in source can only commit to source?

Comment: if u really want to do it though, my idea would be to do `git status` and `grep` on the paths. If it has both source adn test path do not allow the commit. As for where the dev started working check the timestamp of all the changed files and take the first changed file.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this—that is, read the branch name and choose what you'll allow in the next commit based on that name—but that's a *bad idea*, for two reasons:

1. *Git branch names are meaningless*.  It's entirely possible to use multiple different branch names to identify one single commit.  And, if you make branch-name-based restrictions, people will simply invent branch names that don't match either pattern (or use `git commit --no-verify` to skip over the tests entirely).
2. *New code needs new tests.*  When writing new code, it's entirely appropriate to write the new tests *for* that new code at the same time.  The new tests should pass when the new code goes in.

All that said, writing a Git hook is easy: you choose any language you like, and just make sure that the systems (OSes) that you use can run the hooks.  The hooks are just programs that run and produce an exit status.  An exit status of "success" (zero) means that the commit may proceed; a nonzero exit status means that the commit is prohibited.

At the same time, though, writing a *good* Git hook is *hard*.  The code (files) that will go into the new commit is not necessarily the set of files that you see in the working tree.  The code proposed for the new commit is, instead, the files that are in Git's *index* at the time your hook runs.

Important: note that the files that are in Git's index at the time the hook runs, may not exist anywhere at all if the hook exits nonzero.  (If the hook produces a zero exit status, allowing the commit to proceed, the files will wind up in that commit, if nothing else goes wrong.)  In particular, when using `git add --patch` along with `git commit --include` and/or when using `git commit --only`, the files proposed for the new commit are in a *temporary* index that will be deleted when `git commit` itself finishes running.  That temporary index is the *only* place that the to-be-committed files live as a whole.